# What's the second argument to HostListener for and why is it often given as ['$event']?

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular's [`HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) decorator takes two arguments. The first specifies the name of event to listen for. The second is an optional array of strings unilluminatingly named `args`. Naturally, its meaning isn't currently explained in the docs (which currently devote an entire *four words* to documenting the `HostListener` decorator, the first two of which state that it is, uh, the *"HostListener decorator"*).

I've only ever seen `HostListener` called in two ways:

1. Omitting the `args` argument entirely (e.g. at https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-06-01)
2. Specifying the `args` argument as `['$event']`, e.g. at https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/advanced-angular/directives/listening_to_an_element_host.html

What does this mysterious `args` parameter do, and why is it sometimes specified as `['$event']`?

Comment: https://coryrylan.com/blog/listening-to-angular-key-events-with-host-listeners

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`$event` is the reserved name for the actual event value like it can be used in `(click)="clickHandler($event)"` event bindings.

`@HostListener('eventName', args)` supports an array of values like

```
['$event.target.value', '$event.name']
```

that specifies what values will be passed as parameters to the event handler.

It looks like just always passing `$event` (assuming `['$event']` as default) would be a more reasonable approach,
but if WebWorker is used, this way the amount of data passed between UI thread and WebWorker thread can reduced by only passing that part(s) of the event that are actually required by the event handler (or no value at all if the parameter is omitted).

See also https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener#args

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158425/discussion-on-answer-by-gunter-zochbauer-whats-the-second-argument-to-hostliste).

Answer (score 3):

it's the event :)

normal Javascript

```
<div></div>

 div.addEventListener('click', function($event) {
    console.log($event);
  })
```

All the javascript native events, like keyup or click, they're all asynchronous events and when they happen, you can listen to them ( add a listener in Javascript, or a HostListener or event binding in Angular) and then in your function which you are passing to be called when the event is happening, you can catch that Event, which is basically a Javascript object which is holding information about the source of the event and all the other things related to the event.

The same thing can be done in Angular:

```
 @HostListener('click', ['$event']) myFunction(theEvent) {
    console.log("$event is ", theEvent); // 
  }
```

`$event` is an optional parameter and if you're not interested, you're not forced to add it to your parameters.

As I said `$event` holds all the information about the actual event, like the name of it, the source of it, if it was a keyup event, the pressed key and all the other things, that means you can get all those extracted from the `Event`:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event.target.id']) myFunction(buttonId) {
    console.log("buttonId ",buttonId); // 
  }
```

or you can

```
 @HostListener('click', ['$event']) myFunction(event) {
    console.log("buttonId ",event.target.id); // 
  }
```

The other syntax in Angular is :

```
 <button (click)="myFunction($event)">
```

Or in normal javascript you can say :

```
 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',($event)=>{
    console.log('the event is',$event);
})
```

The HostListener can also be written in the @Component decorator if you don't like to use the @HostListener decorator to be used ( although why wouldn't you?)

```
@Component({
   selector:"my-component",
   host:{
    '(click)':'myFunction($event)'
   }
})
```